# How to use tail -f in a loop

Tags: bash, logging, tail

In a bash script, I would like to display the output of another script I launch which execution is quite long and which output, containing a progression bar, is redirected to a file.

I came with the idea of using `tail -f` while the process I launched is still running.

---

Dummy try:

```
#!/bin/bash
./worker.sh & # will log in LOG file
while [[ $(kill -0 $!) ]]; do # my implementation of ps does not support the -p option
    tail -f LOG
done
...
```

This does not work as `tail` "hangs".

---

I found a workaround using the following but I'm pretty sure there is another, cleaner solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
./worker && pkill tail & # I assumed that worker will always return 0
tail -f LOG
...
```

---

So, my question is: What is the best way to display the output of a running process logging in a file without waiting for it to finish ?

Comment: When what's the purpose of running `tail -f` in a loop? When using the `-f` flag the `tail` command will continue to display as the file is updated.

Comment: Indeed, it was a stupid idea

Answer (score 1):

I think you've done it the right way, except that you shouldn't use `&&` because indeed if `./worker` fails, the `tail` process will never be terminated. Instead you can separate the commands with `;`, as in:

```
#!/bin/bash
./worker ; pkill tail &
tail -f LOG
```

Comment: I am currently using `(./worker ; pkill tail) &`  as you suggested. Unfortunately, I cannot accept your answer as I really believe that `--pid` fits better (what would happen if during the execution of worker, another process starts to use `tail` ?)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found what perfectly answer the question:

`tail` has a --pid option:

> ```
>   --pid=PID
>     with -f, terminate after process ID, PID dies
> ```

So the script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
./worker.sh & # will log in LOG file
tail -f --pid=$! LOG
```

Unfortunately, at least my implementation of tail (busybox 1.16.1) does not support this option so I'm still open to workarounds.

Comment: How about: 1) get PID1 of ./worker. 2) run `tail -f` in the background, and get its PID2. 3) use `wait <PID1>` to wait for the worker to finish. 4) `kill <PID2>`

Comment: @this.lau_ Thank you, it works perfectly. May you merge our answers + your comment so that I can accept your answer ?